# PHP No database found

Tags: php

So it says no database selected, please help me as my hosting cant

```
<?php
$sitename = "http://devilgaming.phy.sx/csgopie.xyz/";
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost", "devilgam_csgopie", "ssb12boycek1");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('devilgam_csgopie', $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue)
    {
        if($finder == "1")
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
        else
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE           
`$finder`='$findervalue'") or die (mysql_error());

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row[$rowname];
    }
?>
```

Comment: May I ask why you still are using mysql and no PDO or MySQLi? Also could you give us the fulley error given by PHP itself?

Comment: I dont know tbh, its a script I dont know much about PHP more of a html guy. Came here to see if someone could fix it

Comment: Could you just provide more info? Also remove the @ at the beginning of your $link query

Comment: One might think it's a bad idea to include your username and password in your question.... (I would edit it out myself but it won't let me without adding a paragraph)

Comment: `@mysql_connect` means "connect, but don't tell me if there are any errors". That's going to make debugging difficult.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where is says

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE
   `$finder`='$findervalue'") or die (mysql_error());
```

The mysql_fetch_assoc() function returns an associative array, row by row. To access the rows you would do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row[$rowname];
}
```

Comment: `This is wrong. `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns one row at a time. You're thinking of `PDO::fetchAll` or `mysqli_fetch_all`.

Comment: His function returns a value, it shouldn't echo anything. Whether the value should be echoed depends on what the caller is doing with it.

Comment: In either case, what does this have to do with the `No database selected` error that he's getting? If he gets that error, the query fails, so it doesn't matter how you process the results.

Answer (score -1):

According situations when You install purchased script, or You are comfort with mysql_* functions, I'll not say to switch to mysqli or PDO. PHP 7 will force to switch to modern drivers to everyone (:

but for Your question, run this script and tell me result:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$sitename = "http://devilgaming.phy.sx/csgopie.xyz/";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "devilgam_csgopie", "ssb12boycek1") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('devilgam_csgopie', $link) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname, $tablename, $finder, $findervalue) {
  $q = "SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename";
  if($finder != 1) {
    $q .= " WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'";
  }

  $result = mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  return $row[$rowname];
}
?>
```

Also go to administration panel of hosting create or modify user: devilgam_csgopie to have same username and password.

Because:

> Access denied for user 'devilgam_csgopie'@'localhost' to database

Comment: Says this 
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/devilgam/public_html/csgopie.xyz/set.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'devilgam_csgopie'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/devilgam/public_html/csgopie.xyz/set.php on line 8
Access denied for user 'devilgam_csgopie'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I changed it to my new password new errors 
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/devilgam/public_html/csgopie.xyz/set.php on line 8
Access denied for user 'devilgam_csgopie'@'localhost' to database 'devilgam_csgopie'

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/devilgam/public_html/csgopie.xyz/mysql.php on line 245